# Como chamar o modulo do bootstrap na pagina html em um projeto Node?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, node.js

Estou usando  o **Node** e baixei a dependência do **bootstrap**, mas não sei como,chamar ele na pagina index.html, para usar o arquivo bootstrap.min.css, o que devo fazer?
Tenho a seguinte estrutura de diretórios:

```
----aprendendo 
    ---- config
        ---- express.js 
    ---- node_modules
        ---- bootstrap
        ---- express
    ---- public
        ---- index.html
        ---- outrasPaginas.html
    ---- package.json
    ---- server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap é uma biblioteca para ser usada no cliente, independente de você estar usando Node ou não. O modelo padrão incluso [no site oficial](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) ilustra bem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- As três tags meta acima *precisam* serem as primeiras na head; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *depois* dessas tags -->

    <title>Modelo do tutorial do Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- shim HTML5 and Respond.js para o suporte do IE8 a elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ATENÇÃO: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar a página pelo file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessário para os plugins Javascript do Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Inclua todos os plugins compilados (abaixo), ou inclua um por um quando for necessário -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note que esse exemplo presume que o arquivo bootstrap.min.css está dentro da pasta css, e essa pasta fica no mesmo diretório que esse arquivo HTML. Ajuste de acordo com o seu caso (faça uma busca se precisar descobrir onde foi parar o seu arquivo). A mesma coisa com o arquivo bootstrap.js.

Comment: Obrigado antes de mais nada! Esqueci de editar a  pergunta , o conteúdo de sua resposta já é de meu conhecimento e eu faço isso há um certo tempo!! Mina duvida é como usar o bower para fazer isso para min!!Desculpe vou editar a pergunta!!